# Integrating submit button with on Enter key press for comment box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, this

I am using 10 Comment box in my page. The button works perfectly but now I would like to add functionality that, when I press the enter button then automatically the text is submitted.

How can I add this function without changing much code. I am binding the bsubmit class with the event On click. ( There are 10 comment boxes )

```
    <div class="addcomment" style="display: block; ">
<input class="commentadd" type="text" name="comment" value="Enter Comment" onfocus="if(this.value=='Enter Comment')this.value='';">
<button class="bsubmit" type="button">Submit</button></div>
```

EVENT CODE

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

$(function() {
$(".bsubmit").live("click", function() {
var id = $(this).parent().parent().attr("id");
var comm= document.getElementById(id).getElementsByClassName("commentadd")[0].value;


  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "comment.php",
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('body').on('keyup','input.commentadd', function(e) {
  // e.which is monitoring the key pressed 
  // and 13 is code for enter key
  if(e.which == 13 && $.trim(this.value).length) {
    $(this).next(".bsubmit").click(); // triggering click event on button
  }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FrAw8/7/)**

Comment: but my bsubmit.click is having 
>var id = $(this).parent().parent().attr("id");

So in this case which $(this)  would be invoked ? for which button ? will it invoke the same one ? I have 10 comment box

Comment: @AdiMathur button's $(this), because it trigger the button event and all execution will execute within button's scope

Comment: I Just tried it, this invoked all the button submit. :)  - - - 

Each comment box submitted the default comment "Enter comment "

Comment: I have 10 similar comment boxes , All of them got submitted :-)  .

Comment: @AdiMathur check my update answer and demo and hope you problem will solve

Comment: Perfect !! :)
Thank you so much 
So the  $(this).next(".bsubmit") will search for the very next .bsubmit button isnt it ?